# HttpClient DeleteAsync with Multiple records

Tags: c#, httpclient

I'm using the sendgrid api here:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#Delete-a-Recipient-DELETE

and it shows passing an array of strings to the DELETE call.  When I look at the signature of System.Net.Http.HttpClient, DELETE does not allow for content to be passed in.

Is there a standard around DELETE that does not allow for multiple content passed at the same time?

[image]

API definition:

[image]

Comment: Where does it specify that an array can be passed? Looks like a single value to me.

Comment: I agree with @usr - the method you link to states recipient_id, not ids.

Comment: linked to picture here which shows the doc for multiple recipients and the example:  https://db.tt/n7RCvZmX

Comment: How about using `SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage)` you could even create an extension method that accepts a payload.

Answer (score 0):

[The HTTP/1.1 RFC states that a `DELETE` request's payload has no defined semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5).

It's not illegal to include a payload, but this means that if a payload is included, it should be ignored.

Many HTTP clients, such as the one provided by the .NET framework, don't provide an interface to include a payload when it has no defined semantics for the method.

Unfortunately, many REST APIs do require a payload with these methods. You can accomplish this by manually creating a `HttpRequestMessage` object, setting the `Method` and `Content` properties, and passing it to the HTTP client's `SendAsync` method.

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension method

```
public static class HttpClientExtensions
{
    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> Delete(this HttpClient client, HttpContent content)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage { Method = "DELETE", Content = content);
        return client.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

However I cannot recommend it, as it breaks basic assumptions of HTTP, which allows efficient HTTP Proxies to work.

The "correct method" around this problem is to use HTTP 2.0 (or HTTP 1.1 Pipelining, which is deprecated due to it being mostly broken, but you could try it out) to create multiple DELETE requests. In theory that solution does not require any code change.

Comment: Thanks @Aron  This sounds like an answer I can work with. I had forgotten I could extend the class.  I'll test it out and loop back and mark as answered when I've tested the above.